# I am not able to connect my Filezilla or Putty with Google Cloud through SSH

Tags: filezilla

I followed the steps mentioned here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata
and here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools

1) I create the Key pair using puttygen

2) I copied the public key using my GCE email id as Key Comment at puttygen

3) I pasted the public key to the Google Instance Metadata->SSH keys->Add new

4) I saved the private key and assigned to SSH->Auth section

5) Now i am trying to connect it through putty

In Putty I get "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" error with "server refused our key".

I went through all documentations, but no success. Is there anything I need to to with IAM?

In Filezilla I get the error: "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)".

These are images of what I did
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oSXp.jpg)

Comment: I did it with the screen shot updated

Comment: yes, then what it should be? I even tried replacing it with _ underscore but not getting connected. It is showing me same error.

Comment: I did it that way too. No change in connection message. Is there anything we need to take care in configure at instance level other than Metadata?

Comment: OK, I've done a test with fresh GCE instance. It actually works this way: Whatever you put into the comment box is taken as a username - everything after `@` is ignored - you can see what was takes as a username to the lext of the key box. And that user account is automatically created. So if I add `foobar` into the comment, I can then login with `foobar` username and my key. I didn't set anything else.

Comment: What is the meaning of "server refused our key", a message in Putty. in what condition this messages shows up. Is it anything related to IAM configuration?

Comment: The meaning is that your key is not set up correctly on the server. -- Can you try to set up the key on a new VM instance? (Documenting every step with a screenshot)

Comment: Yes, I created new instance and I was able to connect to that instance on first trial with both, Putty and FileZilla. Whats wrong with the previous one didnt get. But this is still not my solution.

Comment: I am able to reassign the service account to my instance but still I am not able to connect my instance with putty and private key.

Comment: As per my previous comment: The key comment must match the username you use to connect to the server - Does it? Are you logging in with username `xxxx_gmail_com`?

Comment: Yes I tried it but not able to login. on the other hand I do not face this issue at new instance under the same project. I am able to login with username "lamp-1" which is different from "xxxx_gmail_com".

Comment: I am surprised, like nobody has an idea how this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem two times.

1. it was because Google Cloud shell extension on chrome used different credentials. Discover this after using another browser.
2. it was because the SSH keys on Computing "Engine" -> "Metadata" was not accessible on the VM instance. I inserted the same key directly on the instance details and I got it to work.